# Fill secondly data from Q KDB+

Tags: loops, kdb, q-lang

I have a csv file with some high frequency stock price data, and I'd like to get a secondly price data from the table.

In each file, there are columns named `date`, `time`, `symbol`, `price`, `volume`, and etc.

There are some seconds with no trading so there are missing data in some seconds.

I'm wondering how could I fill the missing data in Q to get the secondly data from 9:30 to 16:00 in full? If there is missing price, just use the recently price as its price in that second.

I'm considering to write some loop, but I don't know how to exactly to that.

Comment: Can you add an example of any code that you already have, along with the code where you are currently pulling the data? Read   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on how to write a good question.

Comment: I've solved the problem using aj. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying a little, I'll assume you have some random timestamps in your dataset like this:

```
time                            price
--------------------------------------
2015.01.20D22:42:34.776607000   7
2015.01.20D22:42:34.886607000   3
2015.01.20D22:42:36.776607000   4
2015.01.20D22:42:37.776607000   8
2015.01.20D22:42:37.886607000   7
2015.01.20D22:42:39.776607000   9
2015.01.20D22:42:40.776607000   4
2015.01.20D22:42:41.776607000   9
```

so there are some missing seconds there. I'm going to call this table `t`. So if you do a by-second type of query, obviously the seconds that are missing are still missing:

```
q)select max price by time.second from t
second  | price
--------| -----
22:42:34| 7
22:42:36| 4
22:42:37| 8
22:42:39| 9
22:42:40| 4
22:42:41| 9
```

To get missing seconds, you have to join a list of nulls. In this case we know the data goes from 22:42:34 to 22:42:41, but in reality you'll have to find the min/max time and use that to create a temporary "null" table to join against:

```
q)([] second:22:42:34 + til 1+`int$22:42:41-22:42:34 ; price:(1+`int$22:42:41-22:42:34)#0N)
second   price
--------------
22:42:34
22:42:35
22:42:36
22:42:37
22:42:38
22:42:39
22:42:40
22:42:41
```

Then left join:

```
q)([] second:22:42:34 + til 1+`int$22:42:41-22:42:34 ; price:(1+`int$22:42:41-22:42:34)#0N) lj select max price by time.second from t
second   price
--------------
22:42:34 7
22:42:35
22:42:36 4
22:42:37 8
22:42:38
22:42:39 9
22:42:40 4
22:42:41 9
```

You can use `fills` or whatever your favourite filling heuristic is after that.

```
q)fills `second xasc asc ([] second:22:42:34 + til 1+`int$22:42:41-22:42:34 ; price:(1+`int$22:42:41-22:42:34)#0N) lj select max price by time.second from t
second   price
--------------
22:42:34 7
22:42:35 7
22:42:36 4
22:42:37 8
22:42:38 8
22:42:39 9
22:42:40 4
22:42:41 9
```

(Note the sort on `second` before `fills`!)

By the way for larger tables this will be *much* faster than a loop. Loops in q are generally a bad idea.

**EDIT**

You could use a comma join too, both tables need to be keyed on the `second` column

```
t,t1
```

(where t1 is the null-filled table keyed on `second`)

I haven't tested it, but I suspect it would be slightly faster than the `lj` version.

Comment: aj will also work - make sure the table is sorted though, because it does a binary search to find the nearest match. It will be much slower than my solution too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `aj` which is one of the most powerful features of KDB:

```
q)data
sym  time     price     size
----------------------------
MS   10:24:04 93.35974  8
MS   10:10:47 4.586986  1
APPL 10:50:23 0.7831685 1
GOOG 10:19:52 49.17305  0
```

in-memory table needs to be `sym`,`time` sorted with `g#` attribute applied to `sym` column

```
q)data:update `g#sym from `sym`time xasc data
q)meta trade
c    | t f a
-----| -----
sym  | s   g
time | v
price| f
size | j
```

Creating a `rack` table intervalized per second per sym :

```
q)rack: `sym`time xasc (select distinct sym from data) cross   ([] time:{x[0]+til `int$x[1]-x[0]}(min;max)@\:data`time)
```

Using `aj` to join the data :

```
q)aj[`sym`time; rack; data]
```